# Basic JSON Parsing Query

Tags: c#, json

So I am using [JSON.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for a research based project. My sample JSON file looks like this. The file is huge but bear with me, I just need to process one part of it:

```
{
  "connectionName" : "example.com",
  "connectionPort" : 443,
  "SNI" : "example.com",
  "SSLv3" : {
    "suiteSelection" : "server",
    "suites" : [
      {
        "id" : 49169,
        "name" : "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : true,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 49171,
        "name" : "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : true,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 49172,
        "name" : "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : true,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 47,
        "name" : "RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : false,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 53,
        "name" : "RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : false,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 5,
        "name" : "RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : false,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      }
    ]
  },
  "TLSv1.0" : {
    "suiteSelection" : "server",
    "suites" : [
      {
        "id" : 49169,
        "name" : "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : true,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 49171,
        "name" : "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : true,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 49172,
        "name" : "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : true,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 47,
        "name" : "RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : false,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 53,
        "name" : "RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : false,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 5,
        "name" : "RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : false,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      }
    ]
  },
  "TLSv1.1" : {
    "suiteSelection" : "server",
    "suites" : [
      {
        "id" : 49169,
        "name" : "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : true,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 49171,
        "name" : "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : true,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 49172,
        "name" : "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : true,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 47,
        "name" : "RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : false,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 53,
        "name" : "RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : false,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 5,
        "name" : "RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : false,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      }
    ]
  },
  "TLSv1.2" : {
    "suiteSelection" : "server",
    "suites" : [
      {
        "id" : 49199,
        "name" : "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : true,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 49191,
        "name" : "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : true,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 49169,
        "name" : "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : true,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 49171,
        "name" : "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : true,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 49172,
        "name" : "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : true,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 49200,
        "name" : "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : true,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 49192,
        "name" : "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : true,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 156,
        "name" : "RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : false,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 157,
        "name" : "RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : false,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 60,
        "name" : "RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : false,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 47,
        "name" : "RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : false,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 61,
        "name" : "RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : false,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 53,
        "name" : "RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : false,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      },
      {
        "id" : 5,
        "name" : "RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
        "strength" : 3,
        "forwardSecrecy" : false,
        "anonymous" : false,
        "serverKeyType" : "RSA"
      }
    ]
  },
  "ssl3Chains" : [
    {
      "length" : 3,
      "decoded" : true,
      "namesMatch" : true,
      "includesRoot" : false,
      "signHashes" : [
        "SHA-1",
        "SHA-256"
      ],
      "certificates" : [
        {
          "thumbprint" : "4F851C51052200FE11C8BBFA1ED4BD29CFC7CB16",
          "decodable" : true,
          "serialHex" : "773A528C676E2348E3E6ED494D6A5EC9",
          "subject" : "CN=www.example.cn,OU=service operation department,O=BeiJing example Netcom Science Technology Co.\\, Ltd,L=beijing,ST=beijing,C=CN",
          "issuer" : "CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4,OU=Symantec Trust Network,O=Symantec Corporation,C=US",
          "validFrom" : "2016-04-10 00:00:00 UTC",
          "validTo" : "2017-04-11 23:59:59 UTC",
          "keyType" : "RSA",
          "keySize" : 2048,
          "signHash" : "SHA-256",
          "selfIssued" : false,
          "serverNames" : [
            "example.cn",
            "example.com",
            "example.com.cn",
            "w.example.com",
            "ww.example.com",
            "www.example.cn",
            "www.example.com.cn",
            "www.example.com.hk",
            "www.example.hk",
            "www.example.net.au",
            "www.example.net.my",
            "www.example.net.ph",
            "www.example.net.pk",
            "www.example.net.tw",
            "www.example.net.vn",
            "wwww.example.com",
            "wwww.example.com.cn"
          ]
        },
        {
          "thumbprint" : "FF67367C5CD4DE4AE18BCCE1D70FDABD7C866135",
          "decodable" : true,
          "serialHex" : "513FB9743870B73440418D30930699FF",
          "subject" : "CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4,OU=Symantec Trust Network,O=Symantec Corporation,C=US",
          "issuer" : "CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5,OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign\\, Inc. - For authorized use only,OU=VeriSign Trust Network,O=VeriSign\\, Inc.,C=US",
          "validFrom" : "2013-10-31 00:00:00 UTC",
          "validTo" : "2023-10-30 23:59:59 UTC",
          "keyType" : "RSA",
          "keySize" : 2048,
          "signHash" : "SHA-256",
          "selfIssued" : false
        },
        {
          "thumbprint" : "32F30882622B87CF8856C63DB873DF0853B4DD27",
          "decodable" : true,
          "serialHex" : "250CE8E030612E9F2B89F7054D7CF8FD",
          "subject" : "CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5,OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign\\, Inc. - For authorized use only,OU=VeriSign Trust Network,O=VeriSign\\, Inc.,C=US",
          "issuer" : "OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority,O=VeriSign\\, Inc.,C=US",
          "validFrom" : "2006-11-08 00:00:00 UTC",
          "validTo" : "2021-11-07 23:59:59 UTC",
          "keyType" : "RSA",
          "keySize" : 2048,
          "signHash" : "SHA-1",
          "selfIssued" : false
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "deflateCompress" : false,
  "serverTime" : "random",
  "secureRenegotiation" : true,
  "minECSize" : 256,
  "minECSizeExt" : 256,
  "namedCurves" : [
    {
      "name" : "secp256r1 (P-256)",
      "size" : 256,
      "spontaneous" : true
    }
  ],
  "warnings" : [
    {
      "id" : "CS005",
      "text" : "Server supports RC4."
    },
    {
      "id" : "CS006",
      "text" : "Server supports cipher suites with no forward secrecy."
    },
    {
      "id" : "PV003",
      "text" : "Server supports SSL 3.0."
    },
    {
      "id" : "XC001",
      "text" : "Server certificate was signed with a weak/deprecated/unknown hash function."
    }
  ]
}
```

So I just want to print the `name` to the output window so I created the simple `CName` class. Here is my code:

```
public class CName
{
     public string name { get; set; }
}

DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\output_v_2\");
FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.json");

foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    CName read_data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CName>(File.ReadAllText(file.Name));
    Debug.WriteLine(read_data.name);
}
```

**EDIT**: Seems my understanding of JSON is really poor. What I am trying to do is this: from `"name" : "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",` and all similar lines with `"name"`, I need those `ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA` type values that I fail to get.
However all I get is blank output.
Suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no `name` property in the root of your json.

Comment: @PaulAbbott I am new to this, how do I access `name` then?

Comment: what "name"? as @PaulAbbott said there's no "name" property on your json object

Comment: I mean this `name` :  `"name" : "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",`, I need the `ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA` value.

Comment: @Gusman Sorry for my poor Json understanding. Added details in question of my intentions.

Comment: Your `CName` class doesn't even come close to matching the structure of your json; just run it through http://json2csharp.com/ and then `DeserializeObject<RootObject>`

Comment: I suggest you to use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/), here you can paste the JSON and get all classes that you need to parse your JSON, then you can use RootObject.property.subProperty.field ....

Comment: @ganchito55 I thought I could just use a small part. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: If you just want a small part maybe you can just use a JToken, if you use DeserializeObject() instead of DeserializeObject<T>() it will return a JToken which has the functions to iterate over it, access it's members like arrays, etc etc.

Comment: @Gusman Great tip, thanks. Can you write it as answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want an small part of the content and don't want to create a full model, you can use `DeserializeObject()` instead of `DeserializeObject<T>()`, that will return a JToken which is an object with the needed functions to iterate over it, access it's members like arrays, etc.

[Here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jtoken.htm) is a link to the documentation of JToken.